# How can I convert these Blender video settings to ffmpeg please?

Tags: video, encoding

Whenever I use the ffmpeg commands, the video is larger and the seeking/keyframe inteval is not the same as the video rendered from Blender. How can I convert the following Blender settings to ffmpeg please?

Blender Settings:

- Frame rate: 30
- Codec: h.264
- Output .mp4
- Keyframe interval: 1
- Output quality: Medium
- Encoding speed: Good

Here's my current command however the seeking and file size is different: `ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i %04d.jpg -g 1 -vcodec libx264 video.mp4`

Comment: My answer was found on stackoverflow for anyone that needs it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67011275/how-can-i-convert-these-blender-video-settings-to-ffmpeg-please/67038271#67038271